# Variable not changing after trying to update it

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a variable update after a line of the code is passed. The problem I'm having is that, once that line of the code is passed and then printed again, the variable is the default one, in this case 10.
I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or anything, but I just can't see where I'm failing, maybe because I'm a beginner. Tried everything I could think of before asking for help but at this point I'm desperate. Thanks.

```
number = 10

def numberFun(question,valid=("ADD","REM")):
    while (answer := input(question)) and answer not in valid:
        print(f"Please, choose between {valid}.") 
    return answer


print(f"{number}: before updating.")
numberAction = numberFun("You want to add or remove one?\n")
if numberAction == "ADD":
    print(number + 1)
elif numberAction == "REM":
    print(number - 1)


print(f"{number} : after updating.")
```

Comment: Are you trying to update the `number` variable? if so, which line do you expect would do the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you aren't updating the value stored in `number`. My guess is that you are trying to do so in your `if`/`elif` clauses; if that is the case, this should work:

```py
number = 10

def numberFun(question,valid=("ADD","REM")):
    while (answer := input(question)) and answer not in valid:
        print(f"Please, choose between {valid}.") 
    return answer

print(f"{number}: before updating.")
numberAction = numberFun("You want to add or remove one?\n")
if numberAction == "ADD":
    number += 1    # equivalent to 'number = number + 1'
elif numberAction == "REM":
    number -= 1    # equivalent to 'number = number - 1'
print(number)


print(f"{number} : after updating.")
```

Originally, you were only printing `number` after some operation. In order for the value in `number` to change, you would need to reassign some value to the variable.

Comment: This worked! I see that my fail was that I was actually printing the result and not updating it. I understand now, what a rookie mistake hahaha... Anyways thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Notice how I perform a computation where you performed output. I moved output below the computations.

```py
number = 10

def numberFun(question,valid=("ADD","REM")):
    while (answer := input(question)) and answer not in valid:
        print(f"Please, choose between {valid}.")
    return answer

print(f"{number}: before updating.")
numberAction = numberFun("You want to add or remove one?\n")
if numberAction == "ADD":
    number = number + 1
elif numberAction == "REM":
    number = number - 1
print(number)

print(f"{number} : after updating.")
```

Answer (score 0):

To add or subtract 1 from the variable `num` you need to do addition or subtraction operation on the value and store that in the same variable to "update" it.

In your code, in line 12 and line 14, you do the addition, subtraction respectively but you print the result instead of storing the result in the variable `number` which would "update" the prestored value which in this case is 10.

So, replacing `print(number + 1)` from line 12 with `number += 1` to add 1 to the previous value and replacing `print(number - 1)` from line 14 with `number -= 1` to subtract one to "update" the stored value based on the user's choice.

Then, in the last line when you print the number variable it will display the "updated" value of the variable `number`

```py
number = 10

def numberFun(question,valid=("ADD","REM")):
    while (answer := input(question)) and answer not in valid:
        print(f"Please, choose between {valid}.") 
    return answer


print(f"{number}: before updating.")
numberAction = numberFun("You want to add or remove one?\n")
if numberAction == "ADD":
    number += 1
elif numberAction == "REM":
    number -= 1


print(f"{number} : after updating.")
```